# How To Save XML Query Results to a File

Tags: sql-server, xml

I have an SQL query and I am using For XML Path to generate the result as an XML.

Can anyone help me about converting that XML output into "**a.xml**" file and save in a particular folder of a computer?

Also want to know, is there any method other than *BCP* to achieve this?

Comment: Which client are you use?

Comment: Im using sql server management studio 2012

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could try using [`xp_cmdshell`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175046.aspx)....

```sql
-- Read your query results into an XML variable
DECLARE @xml AS XML = (SELECT * FROM YourTable FOR XML PATH)

-- Cast the XML variable into a VARCHAR
DECLARE @xmlChar AS VARCHAR(max) = CAST(@xml AS VARCHAR(max))

-- Escape the < and > characters
SET @xmlChar = REPLACE(REPLACE(@xmlChar, '>', '^>'), '<', '^<')

-- Create command text to echo to file
DECLARE @command VARCHAR(8000) = 'echo ' + @xmlChar + ' > c:\test.txt'

-- Execute the command
EXEC xp_cmdshell @command
```

You could also try a Powershell command if you wanted a bit more control e.g. to set encoding...

```sql
DECLARE @command VARCHAR(8000) = 'powershell -Command "Set-Content -Encoding UTF8 C:\test.txt \"' + @xmlChar + '\""'
```

A few notes...

There is an 8000 character length limit on the command, so it's no good for large files.

If you save the file to a mapped drive, it will look for that drive on the database server. So, C:\ will be referring to the C:\ drive of the server, not where you are running Management Studio.

Special permissions are required to run `xp_cmdshell`.

Click [**here**](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175046.aspx) for more details.

Comment: That was exactly what I looking for

Comment: What an answer, I spent days trying to find this solution and when I found this answer my issue was resolved in seconds. Wow thanks @davmos