# create and store large XML output in SQL

Tags: sql-server, xml, sql-server-2008, ssms

I have a query that gives approximately **four hundred thousand records** [400000], up to *18mb*.
I parsed the output to XML output, using:

```
for xml path('url'), Root('urlset')
```

Now, query result doesn't show complete XML. 
when I try to view in XML SQL window, not able to export in an XML file.

**ERROR:**

[image: test]

I have done below practices as suggested in other posts:

- [Run This Script](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18781126/3682162) to enable xp_cmdshell
- Increase [XML data capacity](http://blog.extreme-advice.com/2013/03/05/error-fix-unable-to-show-xml-the-following-error-happened-there-is-an-unclosed-literal-string/) to **Unlimited** in Options >> Result to Grid

Still the same error! How to resolve this?

Comment: try to restart SSMS after `Increase XML data capacity to Unlimited in Options >> Result to Grid` or create new query window and execute your query there

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a while, I tried what @gofr1 referred in his comment.

[image: This Practice]

Above practice doesn't become effective on opening new Query window/ Refreshing the Database connection.

**It works ONLY AFTER Restarting SSMS.**

*update* NOTE: With this solution, you can see **Results in Grid**, but if you try to export it to XML file. you will get the same error.

> Exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' was thrown.

***UPDATE:***

so, here I decided to pass the XML output to an application and let the C# generate XML file in the desired folder.

As [Google sitemap XML limit](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34972582/3682162) is : **50,000**. So, one should create the number of sitemaps each containing max 50k records.

Note: **Google allows 1000 sitemap files for each domain**.

### **EDIT:**

Google has increased the maximum limit from 1,000 sitemaps to **50,000 Sitemaps**, a sitemap file size can be maximum up to **50mb**. This is a huge increase in capacity.

*References:*

1. [seroundtable/archives/021559](https://www.seroundtable.com/archives/021559.html)
2. [searchengineland/google-bing-increase-file-size-limit-sitemaps-files](https://searchengineland.com/google-bing-increase-file-size-limit-sitemaps-files-264338)
3. [searchenginejournal/google-bing-increase-sitemap-file-size-limit-50](https://www.searchenginejournal.com/google-bing-increase-sitemap-file-size-limit-50-mb/180017/)

Answer (score 0):

This is because SSMS not able to show a large amount of data in the result window. 
You can write a utility and dump the data into the file for better readability.